# C++ Initiating object with array in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

I am trying to initiate an object with an array. Is there a way to do it with pointers or should i find another way to do this.

EDIT: I want to write this code with dynamic memory allocation, I know vector is better way to solve this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class t>
class die {
private:
    int sideCount;
    t* valueOfSides;
public:
    die(int side, t arr[]) {
        sideCount = side;
        valueOfSides = (t*)malloc(side * sizeof(t));
        for (int counter; counter < side; counter++) {
            valueOfSides[counter] = val[counter];
        }
    }

    ~die() {
        free(valueOfSides);
    }
};

int main() {
    die<int> sixsided(6, {1,2,3,4,5,6});
}
```

Comment: You should definitely find a different way to do this. Using `malloc` and `free` in pure C++ code will always result in a major disaster. In which textbook did you learn to use `malloc` and `free` in C++? That's C, and there is never a valid reason to use `malloc` and `free` in pure C++ code.

Comment: I know std::vector is c++ way to declare arrays but I don't think this is the problem for now

Comment: Sure it is. Because if the parameter to the constructor was `const std::vector<t> &` (and the rest of the template class adjusted accordingly), then two things will immediately happen. 1) There wouldn't be any reason for the 2nd parameter to the constructor, explicitly giving the number of values, since this now can be trivially obtained from `t.size()`, and 2) `die<int> sixsided({1,2,3,4,5,6});` would actually compile! I'm still curious which C++ textbook claims that the right way to do this is with `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand, so you are saying there is no way to do it with dynamic memory allocation(in c I cant use vector).

Comment: Is this a C question or a C++ question?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "dynamic memory allocation", but with the C++ syntax. One cannot deduce a pointer from a braced initialization list. The only context where anything remotely similar happens is with string literals, where `"literal string"` gets deduced to a `const char []`, which then decays to a `const char *`.

Comment: @Casey c++ question using dynamic memory allocation, but this part of the code looks like c for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The right ways to do this would be

```
std::vector<t> valueOfSides;

template<size_t len> die(t (&arr)[len])
: valueOfSides(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr))
{}
```

or

```
std::vector<t> valueOfSides;

die(std::initializer_list<t> arr) : valueOfSides(arr) {}
```

I think. Though really, the best answer is

```
std::vector<t> valueOfSides;

die(std::vector<t> arr) : valueOfSides(std::move(arr)) {}
```

One should never use raw pointers to own memory in C++, and virtually never use `new` or `malloc`.  As it is, you have undefined behavior in your code because of misusing `malloc`.

---

If you're absolutely insane, or doing homework, it can be done with raw pointers, though I doubt I can get it entirely right without tests and a compiler.

```
template<class t>
class die {
private:
    int sideCount;
    t* valueOfSides;
public:
    die(int side, t* arr) {
        sideCount = 0;
        std::size_t buffer_size = sizeof(t)*side;
        char* buffer;
        try {
            buffer = new char[side];
            valueOfSides = reinterpret_cast<t*>(buffer);
            for(int i=0; i<side; i++) {
                new(valueOfSides+i)t(arr[i]);
                sideCount++;
            }
        } catch(...) {
            for(int i=sideCount; i>=0; i--)
                (valueOfSides+i)->~t();
            delete[]buffer;
            throw;
        }
    }
    die& operator=(die&& rhs) {
        sideCount = rhs.sideCount;
        valueOfSides = rhs.valueOfSides;
        rhs.valueOfSides = nullptr;
        rhs.sideCount = 0;
        return *this;
    }
    //die& operator=(const die& rhs) not shown because its super hard.

    ~die() {
        for(int i=sideCount; i>=0; i--)
            (valueOfSides+i)->~t();
        delete[]reinterpret_cast<char*>(valueOfSides);
    }
};
```

As we've said before, getting this stuff right is crazy hard.  Use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <initalizer_list>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class die {
public:
    die() = default;
    die(std::initializer_list<T> list)
    : sides{list}
    { /* DO NOTHING */ }
private:
    std::vector<T> sides{};
};

int main() {
    die<int> sixsided({1,2,3,4,5,6});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this, using more of a C technique, is a variable argument list:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

template <class t>
class die {
private:
    int sideCount;
    t* valueOfSides;
public:
    die(int side, ...) {
        sideCount = side;
        valueOfSides = new t[side];

        va_list args;
        va_start(args, side);
        for (int counter = 0; counter < side; counter++) {
            valueOfSides[counter] = va_arg(args, t);
        }
        va_end(args);
    }

    ~die() {
        delete[] valueOfSides;
    }
};

int main() {
    die<int> sixsided(6, 1,2,3,4,5,6);
}
```

Rather than passing an array, you're passing the parameters individually (i.e. no need for a temporary array) and using a `va_list` to access them.

Also, the calls to `malloc` and `free` were replaced with `new` and `delete` which is the C++ way of allocating and deallocating memory.